# Searching based on parent relationship

Tags: low-search

I'm working on a search section of a site which allows users to find a list of shops based on their categories.

I would also like to find shops that have offers.

Offer entries have a relationship field which links it back to the shop entry.

With Low Search, is it possible to run this psuedo code?

**Give me all of the shops from category 2 that are a parent to an open offer**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two filters in play here, especially if you slightly re-phrase your last sentence:

> Give me all of the shops from category 2 **and** that are a parent to an open offer

First of all, you need the [**Categories filter**](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories). And because you're just after a single category, you can use the native category="" parameter.

Secondly, you need the [**Relationships filter**](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#relationships) for the second half. This is slightly trickier. The Relationships filter, like the Categories filter, accepts IDs. With the Categories filter, you're selecting which category to filter by; with the Relationships filter, you're selecting *entries* rather than categories.

However in your case, you're not selecting entries. You're after a *pre-defined list of entries*: "open offers". So, what you're really after is a way to populate the Relationships parameter with a pipe-separated list of entry_ids: the open offers.

Also note: you're saying "a parent to an open offer", but they way you described the relationship, *an offer is a parent to a shop*:

> Offer entries have a relationship field which links it back to the shop entry.

For the Relationships filter, you therefore need to define the parent:*field_name* parameter, where the *field_name* is the Relationship field in the Offers channel, and the parameter contains Offer entry IDs.

As a parameter string, it would look something like this:

```
{exp:low_search:results channel="shop" category="2" parent:field_name="1|2|3"}
```

...where `field_name` should be replaced with the actual relationship field name, and `1|2|3` is the pipe separated list of "open offer" entry IDs.

Comment: Brilliant - that worked like a charm. Thanks for the help Low. I have built a basic plugin at https://github.com/andrewfairlie/rc_open_entries that returns the entry_ids for offers for me and may be of use to others.